# Count array with condition

Tags: ruby

So I have a array of characters and I'd like to display all permutations of a given size meeting a certain condition. For instance, if my array contains `'L'`, `'E'` and `'A'` and I choose to display all permutations of size `3` that ends with `'L'`. There are two possibilities, `["A", "E", "L"]` and `["E", "A", "L"]`.

My problem is: how can I count the number of possibilities and print all the possibilities within the same `each`? Here's what I have so far:

```
count = 0
combination_array.select do |item|
  count += 1 if item.last == 'L'
  puts "#{item} " if item.last == 'L'
end
```

It works fine, but I have to write the condition 2 times and also I can't write before displaying all possibilities. I've created a method

```
def count_occurrences(arr)
  counter = 0
  arr.each do |item|
    counter += 1 if item.last == 'L'
  end
  counter
end
```

but I still have to repeat my condition (`item.last == 'L'`). it doesn't seem very efficient to me.

Comment: Can the array include duplicates? If so, and if `arr = ['L', 'A', 'A']` does ['A', 'A', 'L']` count as one or two permutations of `arr`?

Comment: You've seen my comment but have not answered my questions. Please do so.

Comment: @Marcelo Do you still need help with this? Do any of the below answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `each_cons` ([docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)) to iterate through each set of 3 items, and `count` ([docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count)) in block form to have Ruby count for you without constructing a new array:

```rb
matches = [["E", "A", "L"], ["A", "E", "L"]]
match_count = data.each_cons(3).count do |set| 
  if matches.include?(set)
    puts set.to_s
    return true
  end
end
```

If you really dislike the conditional block, you could technically simplify to a one-liner:

```rb
stuff_from_above.count do |set|
  matches.include?(set) && !(puts set.to_s)
end
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `puts` always evaluates to `nil`.

And if you're feeling extra lazy, you can also write `["A", "E", "L"]` as `%w[A E L]` or `"AEL".chars`.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to display and count permutations that end in "L", and the array `arr` is known to contain exactly one "L", the most efficient method is to simply generate permutations of the array with "L" removed and then tack "L" onto each permutation:

```
arr = ['B', 'L', 'E', 'A']
str_at_end = 'L'
```

```
ar = arr - [str_at_end]
  #=> ["B", "E", "A"]     
ar.permutation(2).reduce(0) do |count,a|
  p a + [str_at_end]
  count += 1
end
  #=> 6
```

displaying:

```
["B", "E", "L"]
["B", "A", "L"]
["E", "B", "L"]
["E", "A", "L"]
["A", "B", "L"]
["A", "E", "L"]
```

If you want to do something else as well you need to state specifically what that is.

Note that the number of permutations of the elements of an array of size `n` is simply `n!` (`n` factorial), so if you only need the number of permutations with `L` at the end you could compute that as `factorial(arr.size-1)`, where `factorial` is a simple method you would need to write.

Comment: With Ruby v2.7 we are able to compute the factorial of `n` as follows: `Enumerator.produce([1,1]) {|n0, n1| [n0+1, (n0+1)*n1]}.take(n).last.last`. See [Enumerator::produce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce).